# htaccess redirect issue while redirecting subfolder to sub domain

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I need to redirect subfolder to subdomain using htaccess

I need to redirect

example.com/test,

to https://user.example.com/test

I have the below rule

```
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^test/?$ https://user.example.com/test [R=301,L]
```

How do I modify this rule to satisfy the above condition?

Comment: Also, I need to redirect http://example.com/test,
https://example.com/test to https://user.example.com/test

and also I need to redirect user.example.com/test to https://user.example.com/test

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^user\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^test/?$ https://user.example.com/test [R=301,L,NC,NE]
```

Test this in a new browser to avoid old cache.

Comment: This rule already satisfies all those conditions. Let me know which one it doesn't.

Comment: can u modify the given rule to also satisfy 

example.com/test, http:example.com/test,  https:example.com/test, and user.example.com/test to https:user.example.com/test

Comment: do you want me to add the rule you gave below the existing rule in htaccess?

Comment: This rule should replace your existing rule and should be just below `RewriteEngine` line.

Comment: if I remove the existing I will miss redirect from www.example.com/test to https:user.example.com/test

Comment: No that's not correct. Above rule of mine will take care of `www.example.com/test to https:user.example.com/test` as I have negation in `RewriteCond`.